# Mobile - reading the weather forecast from the device

Tags: android, xamarin, weather, weather-api, openweathermap

I have been looking at weather apis to return daily temperature forecasts. The most satisfactory price-wise (openweathermap) was not giving accurate results. The suggestion was to retrieve the information from the device that is available in the weather widget. I looked at the Awareness API (https://blog.xamarin.com/google-awareness-api-for-android-query-and-react-to-signals/) but the application will not be distributed via the Play Store. 
Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Maybe out of topic but I already have troubles with OpenWeatherMap too and I'm using World Weather Online which has great information and a free plan that can be extended paying depending on your needs.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe that Play distribution is required for an app to use Play Services.

Comment: @Jason is correct, you do not have to use Play distribution to use the Awareness APIs... Now what you get back from the Awareness Weather API is the *current* weather at the user's location, for "awareness" style apps, i.e. tell the user to grab rain jacket/umbrella when leaving the fenced area (office/home/..), apply sun-screen if they are going jogging based upon calendar/time of day, etc... If you are looking for "forecasts", you will have to look elsewhere...

Comment: forecast.io is a great little API for apps like this. 1000 free calls per day. That should be plenty for the use-case of an unlisted app.